# i can't update database using code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm using controller to call update function from model, but when i  try to update for column name, that's no working.

---- Controller ----

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class editprofile extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('namalengkap', 'namalengkap', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'PASSWORD', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->load->view('v_profile');
        } else {
            $row = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'kecamatan' => $this->input->post('kecamatan'),
                'kelurahan' => $this->input->post('kelurahan'),
                'rt' => $this->input->post('rt'),
                'rw' => $this->input->post('rw'),
                'zip code' => $this->input->post('zip code'),
                'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                'province' => $this->input->post('province'),
            );
            $result = $this->user->update($data, $row);
            if ($result > 0) {
                $this->updateProfil();
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', show_succ_msg('Data Profile Berhasil diubah, silakan lakukan login ulang!'));
                redirect('c_login/profile');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', show_err_msg('Data Profile Gagal diubah'));
                redirect('c_login/profile');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

----- model -----

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Model
{

    private $uid = 'id';
    private $tabel = 'users';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function login($email, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        return $this->db->get($this->tabel);
    }


    function update($data, $id)
    {

        $this->db->where($this->uid, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->tabel, $data);
    }

    public function get_by_cookie($kue)
    {
        $this->db->where('cookie', $kue);
        return $this->db->get($this->tabel);
    }
}
```

----- Core / MY_Controller -----

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user');
    }

    public function updateProfil()
    {
        if ($this->userdata != '') {
            $data = $this->user->select($this->userdata->email);

            $this->session->set_userdata('userdata', $data);
            $this->userdata = $this->session->userdata('userdata');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it give any error message?

Answer (score 0):

In your update function you have not **set** any values. As **set** method required array values you should give if. Good practice is using **set** before **update** and finally update of table. Follow the following codes for updating your **users** table.

```
function update($data, $id)
{
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where($this->uid, $id);
    $this->db->update($this->tabel);
}
```

use this code. I hope it will work well.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
$result = $this->user->update($data, $row);
```

variable data is array

so in your model:

```
function update($data=array(), $id){
$this->db->where($this->uid, $id);
$this->db->update($this->tabel, $data);
}
```

Comment: but still not working, i check my table but not change

Comment: in your model after function update($data=array(), $id){ try to var_dump($data);die; , show what's the result?